# Using dynamic SQL to create single 'cell' string. Returning this string via SELECT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, function, t-sql

The following should ultimately return a single scalar value that is a string separated list of account numbers for supplier with ID 1179. With the LEFT function, this works as intended. Without the LEFT function, I see only 'Command(s) completed successfully'. 
I've looked at the QUOTENAME function documentation and it says it is only capable of returning a 128 character string. Is that why I can't see the full list of accounts (easily in excess of 128 characters)? 
Is there some way to achieve what I want using another method?

Code:

```
DECLARE @str1 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @str2 VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @str1 = LEFT(STUFF(
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + cpl.clplAcNo
    FROM tblSuppliers s
    JOIN tblClientPriceLists cpl ON (cpl.clplSupplierId = supRowID)
    WHERE s.supRowID = 1179
        AND clplAcNo IS NOT NULL AND clplAcNo <> ''
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, ''), 300)

SET @str2 = 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@str1, CHAR(39))

EXEC(@str2)
```

Comment: Um, why is this dynamic SQL?

Comment: why is it not dynamic SQL?

Comment: There are all sorts of things that can go wrong with dynamic SQL, it's best used only where you have no alternative. The example above looks like it can be written as a simple SELECT unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I think it was me who was missing something - thanks for your time Rhys.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do:

```
Select SupplierID + ',' anothercolumn + ',' + LEFT(STUFF(
(
SELECT DISTINCT '', '' + cpl.clplAcNo
FROM tblSuppliers s
JOIN tblClientPriceLists cpl ON (cpl.clplSupplierId = supRowID)
WHERE s.supRowID = 1179
    AND clplAcNo IS NOT NULL AND clplAcNo <> ''''
FOR XML PATH('''')
), 1, 1, ''''), 300)
```

Comment: I need more than just the single, comma separated scalar, sorry I didn't make that clear. I also need, on the same row, the supplierID and some other values that I have yet to pick up.
The 
    SET @str2 = 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@str1, CHAR(39))
part of the code will ultimately contain a FROM clause.

Comment: @hwilson1 Is the edited what you're looking for? Not sure you need it in dynamic SQL, depends on if you're adding in variables to your select or not. The above will perform the xml path adding on the supplier ID to the single scalar value. As you can see to add others just concatenate them on. I added the commas in case you wanted them but obviously you can take them out.

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted, thanks Christian. The only context in which I've used FOR XML to return a comma separated list was in creating dynamic pivots so I was steering my query towards a similar structure. Makes perfect sense that you'd just use a nested (SELECT ... ) to return a scalar in the outer query SELECT clause

Comment: @hwilson1 No problem, if you are happy with the answer would you mind accepting it so that others know it has been answered? It will also give you some reputation I believe. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the MSDN docs for [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114(v=sql.100).aspx), note the sentence about the first parameter "*Is a string of Unicode character data. character_string is sysname and is limited to 128 characters. Inputs greater than 128 characters return NULL.*"

As mentioned above, dynamic SQL is best avoided if you can. You could use this instead of dynamic SQL, and you can easily add a FROM clause to bring back other data.

```
SELECT (LEFT(STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + cpl.clplAcNo
                    FROM tblSuppliers s
                    JOIN tblClientPriceLists cpl ON (cpl.clplSupplierId = supRowID)
                    WHERE s.supRowID = 1179
                        AND clplAcNo IS NOT NULL AND clplAcNo <> ''
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                   ), 
                   1, 1, ''
                  ), 300
            )
       ) as AcNos
```